# Set Anaconda2 as default instead of the 'official' python 2.7 on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda

I have both Anaconda2 and Python2.7 installed on my computer (the Python2.7 was downloaded and installed directly form the www.python.org website). I want to use Anaconda2 and not Python2.7 to run my .py files (because Anaconda2 has some libraries that Python2.7 doesn't). However, the default compiler seems to be the one from Python2.7, even though I've added anaconda2 to my PATH (in Environment Variables). I've also tried deleting python2.7 from the PATH.

Has this happen to anyone and how did you resolve it?

Thank you all!

Edit: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Would you tell us your operating system name?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. Sorry, I should've mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the .py files with a double click you have to associate the python interpreter (its an interpreter not a compiler, because it doesn't generate an binary file (.exe)) with the file extension. You can do this if you right click on the file in the file explorer and select open with.

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. I hit "Open with..." and navigated to the python intepreter (in Anaconda2), but when I clicked OK, nothing changed.

Comment: hmm strange. Did it then still open with the interpreter of the python2.7 folder? If you want this change permanently you have to check the tickbox "always open .py files with this program".

Comment: I did. It literally ignored my choice and behaved as if nothing had been changed.

Comment: Well you could try to deinstall the python2.7. Or just rename the python.exe in the python2.7 folder and hope that Windows will then accept your "open with" choice.

Comment: I did try both methods (renaming python.exe and uninstalling python2.7). Didn't work.

Comment: As an alternative if you just need it to start one script, you can write a .bat file which calls the python.exe you want and takes the script as parameter:
`C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\python.exe C:\MyScriptpath\Script.py`

Comment: I'm actually doing something more complicated than that. I'm running an application written in python that requires scipy and numpy libraries. Anaconda2 provides both of these libraries, while the 'official' python2.7 doesn't.

Oh, also, just to be clearer about my previous response, when I uninstalled python2.7 and clicked on a .py file, I got a message asking me to choose a program to run the file; when I then pointed to the python.exe in Anaconda2, nothing changed and my choice was competely ignored, as if anaconda didn't exist on my computer.

Comment: You could also try to install numpy and scipy for your python2.7 installation. If you can't install it with pip you can load binaries from the Gohlke page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Btw, do you mind explaining to me briefly the difference between the binaries vs the version that is installable with pip? I'm someone without a computer science background trying to pick up things here and there

Comment: Pip just downloads the sourcecode and compiles it. This only works if the compiler is set up properly. The binaries are already compiled source code. The binary code contains basically the commands for the cpu to do instead of the code the programmer has written (source code).